# Error using angular and mobile jquery together

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile

I am making an application which uses angular js, jquery and mobile jquery. I used mobile jquery for hamburger menu to swipe from left in android and iphone. Its all working well but gives error in console. That shows `charat undefined in angular.min.js`. I am using angular version 1.3.15. Mobile jquery version 1.4.5 and jquery version 1.11.3. Please help to solve error in console. This is code that i am loading js in body section at the bottom. I loaded mobile jquery css in head section of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.hammer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/contextMenu.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dropdown-enhancements.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-birthday-picker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap2-toggle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-dragdrop.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-sanitize.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/toaster.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/PushNotification.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){$.extend(  $.mobile , {autoInitializePage: false})});</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

And i am firing event of swipe for my menu as below.

```
$(document).on("swiperight", "#touch", function (){});
```

And it is giving me error like below.when i click any button or link.

```
Cannot read property 'CharAt' of undefined in angular.min.js.
```

Thanks.

Comment: without any code to analyze this seems impossible

Comment: Please share your code ?